# Property 'xxxxxx' not found on type org.richfaces.component.UIRepeat

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, el

I'm upgrading from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2 and Richfaces 3.3 to 4.
I've tried various version of JSF2 (2.02, 2.06, etc) and all give the same error.

I'm getting the following error that has been hurting my head for hours now!

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/my-testfile.xhtml]
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /templates/components-navigation.xhtml @31,54 rendered="#{component.allowed}": Property 'allowed' not found on type org.richfaces.component.UIRepeat
```

/templates/components-navigation.xhtml

```
<a4j:outputPanel rendered="#{loginBean.loggedIn}">

    <a4j:repeat var="menugroup" value="#{componentNavigator.groups}">

        <a4j:region rendered="#{menugroup.itemCount > 0}">

            <div class="panel_menu"> 

                <table class="title" border="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h:outputText class="text" value="#{messages[menugroup.id]}" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

                <table class="links" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <a4j:repeat var="component" value="#{componentNavigator.components}">


                            <a4j:region rendered="#{component.allowed}">

                                <a4j:region rendered="#{component.groupId == menugroup.id}">
                                    <tr class="#{component.current?'active':'unactive'}">
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td class="text" width="100%">
                                            <h:commandLink action="#{component.getCommandAction}" actionListener="#{componentNavigator.initControllerBean}">                                        
                                                <span style="display:block;">
                                                    #{messages[component.id]}                                       
                                                </span>
                                                <f:attribute name="controllerBean" value="#{component.controllerBean}" />
                                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{componentNavigator.currentComponent}" value="#{component}" />
                                            </h:commandLink>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </a4j:region>

                            </a4j:region>

                        </a4j:repeat>           
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>

        </a4j:region>

    </a4j:repeat>

</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Line 31 is:

```
<a4j:region rendered="#{component.allowed}">
```

Any ideas why the property is not been found? Is there a know issue with the repeat component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#{component}` is a reserved and implicit EL object which refers to the current JSF component. It can be used as follows:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.value}" styleClass="#{component.valid ? 'ok' : 'error'}" />
```

In the above example, the `#{component}` resolves to an [`UIInput`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) instance representing the current `<h:inputText>`, which in turn has a `isValid()` method. Upon submit, when the component has a validation error, the `error` style class will be set (which may have for example a reddish background color), else the `ok` style class will be set. It's like as `this` in JavaScript.

You should give your scoped variables a different name. Do **not** use the name of one of the following reserved EL objects in JSF:

- `#{component}` - the current [`UIComponent`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html)
- `#{facesContext}` - the current [`FacesContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html)
- `#{request}` - the current [`HttpServletRequest`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)
- `#{session}` - the current [`HttpSession`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)
- `#{application}` - the [`ServletContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)
- `#{cc}` - the current [composite component](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info)
- `#{param}` - the current [request parameter map](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestParameterMap%28%29)
- `#{paramValues}` - the current [request parameter values map](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestParameterValuesMap%28%29)
- `#{requestScope}` - the current [request attribute map](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestMap%28%29)
- `#{viewScope}` - the current [view attribute map](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getViewMap%28%29)
- `#{sessionScope}` - the current [session attribute map](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSessionMap%28%29)
- `#{applicationScope}` - the [application attribute map](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getApplicationMap%28%29)
- `#{header}` - the current [request header map](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestHeaderMap%28%29)
- `#{cookie}` - the current [request cookie map](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestCookieMap%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Your 'component' bean needs a

```
public boolean getAllowed() {
    return this.allowed;
}
```

and

```
public void setAllowed(boolean allowed) {
   this.allowed = allowed;
}
```

method. A property is a field in your bean, which needs a public getter and setter method. Most IDEs support generating those methods look out for something like "Source --> Generate Getter and Setter".

Another possibility would be to call a method directly. Something like,

```
<a4j:region rendered="#{component.isAllowed()}">
```

with a bean code

```
public boolean isAllowed() {
    return this.allowed;
}
```

If you've already getter and setter in your componentNavigator bean it would be usefull if you could post it here (or parts of it).

Richard

Comment: I've already got my getter/setter in my bean, it all worked perfectly in jsf1.2 (No changes made to any beans). It looks it may have something to do with using the the word 'component' as my var.

Answer (score 0):

I changed:

```
<a4j:repeat var="component" value="#{componentNavigator.components}">
```

to:

```
<a4j:repeat var="myComponent" value="#{componentNavigator.components}">
```

and it's all good now :)

I stumbled across this issue which gave me the clue:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-8026